# Remove CSS rules from one HTML image

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working in Wordpress and I have an image inside of a post that I would like to remove the CSS formatting from.

There is a rule in my CSS that gives images backgrounds and I am not sure of the HTML required to remove the CSS rules from just this one image.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**: Right. code would prolly help: Here is the CSS rule that is being given to all the images placed on the site.

```
/* 3.2 Images */

.entry img, img.thumbnail { 
padding: 4px; 
background: #f6f6f6; 
border:2px solid #fff; 
display: block; 
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out; 
-moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out; 
}

.entry img:hover, img.thumbnail:hover { 
box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba( 10, 10, 10, 0.5 ); 
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba( 10, 10, 10, 0.5 ); 
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba( 10, 10, 10, 0.5 );  
}
```

Comment: any code would be appreciated :)

Comment: Good question, but you need to show some code. If you view the source code for the page in question, then show the code surrounding the image in question, we can probably help you.

Comment: You must set new css rule to that one image. Try adding style="background:none" to it.

Comment: Every image inside WP post have some parent with `id`. So target those `id`s or you can target that image with class and `:nth-child()`

Answer (score 1):

create an id that overwrites those rules

```
#justthisonce img{

//css rules for the "one off" image

}
```

html looks like

```
<div id="justthisonce"><img ..... /></div>
```

Comment: Include `!important` to make sure your rule is not overridden as well.

Answer (score 0):

If it's **just one image** in **just one post**

1- From top right of the post edit click on `HTML`

2- Locate the `img` tag of that image.

3- Add this after `<img`

```
style="background-color:none;"
```

So it becomes something like

```
<img style="background-color:none;" src="SourceOfImage" ...>
```

And update your post.

If you want to do this to more images I suggest creating a calss in your style.css of wordpress and applying that class to those images.

Comment: Good call. In the case that there are shadows and boxes on the image, would it be easier to set a class to remove them, and then just apply that class to this one image, or would it be better to just remove them via the "style" html code?

Comment: If you want to do all of these to just one image in your entire website, then just do it inline. If you are going to apply it to more images, then it's better to control it via your css file. Inline styling has priority over styling applied via class definitions, so in case you choose to do it inline you don't need to edit your css file because your inline styling will be effective with higher priority on that img element. You can also set the shadows and other styles via inline styling, just separate them with a semicolon.

Comment: I prefer **ALL styling via CSS files**, I'm suggesting this to you because you are using WordPress and it's just easier to maintain it this way, for just one image.